# Los datos ingresados no se guardan en la base de datos PHP y MySQL de mi sistema

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito guardar los proveedores ingresados al formulario, pero no se guardan los datos en la BD: ese es el problema específico. He revisado e intentado pero no he logrado resolver; envío capturas y código correspondiente a los datos que se ingresan en un formulario, que al darle clic en guardar no se ejecuta tal acción.

He revisado y no he logrado encontrar la falla.

**Controlador**

```php
<?php

class ControladorProveedores{
    /* CREAR PROVEEDORES */

    static public function ctrCrearProveedor(){

        if(isset($_POST["nuevoProveedor"])){

            if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["nuevoProveedor"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["nuevoRif"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ.,#\- ]+$/', $_POST["nuevoNombreProveedor"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[()\0-9 ]+$/', $_POST["nuevoTelefono"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[-0-9 ]+$/', $_POST["nuevaCuenta"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[%\-a-zA-Z0-9.,áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["nuevoBanco"])){

                $tabla = "proveedores";

                $datos = array(
                    "nombre_empresa" => $_POST["nuevoNombreEmpresa"],
                    "rif" => $_POST["nuevoRif"],
                    "nombre_proveedor" => $_POST["nuevoNombreProveedor"],
                    "telefono" => $_POST["nuevoTelefono"],
                    "numero_cuenta" => $_POST["nuevaCuenta"],
                    "banco" => $_POST["nuevoBanco"]);

                $respuesta = ModeloProveedores::mdlIngresarProveedor($tabla, $datos);

                if($respuesta == "ok"){

                    echo '<script>
                        swal({

                            type: "success",
                            title: "El proveedor ha sido guardado correctamente",
                            showConfirmButton: true,
                            confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
                        }).then(function(result){
                            if (result.value) {
                                window.location = "proveedores";

                            }

                        })

                    </script>';

                }

            }else{

                echo '<script>
                    swal({

                        type: "error",
                        title: "¡Por favor, verifica los datos ingresados!",
                        text: "Alguno de los campos contiene caracteres no permitidos.",
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
                    }).then(function(result){
                        if (result.value) {
                            window.location = "proveedores";

                        }

                    })

                </script>';
            }
        }
    }

    /* MOSTRAR PROVEEDORES */

    static public function ctrMostrarProveedores($item, $valor){

        $tabla = "proveedores";

        $respuesta = ModeloProveedores::mdlMostrarProveedores($tabla, $item, $valor);

        return $respuesta;

    }

/* EDITAR PROVEEDOR */

    static public function ctrEditarProveedor(){

        if(isset($_POST["editarProveedor"])){

            if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["editarProveedor"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["editarRif"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ.,#\- ]+$/', $_POST["editarNombreProveedor"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[()\0-9 ]+$/', $_POST["editarTelefono"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[-0-9 ]+$/', $_POST["editarCuenta"]) &&
               preg_match('/^[%\-a-zA-Z0-9.,áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/', $_POST["editarBanco"])){

                $tabla = "proveedores";

                $datos = array(
                    "nombre_empresa" => $_POST["editarNombreEmpresa"],
                    "rif" => $_POST["editarRif"],
                    "nombre_proveedor" => $_POST["editarNombreProveedor"],
                    "telefono" => $_POST["editarTelefono"],
                    "numero_cuenta" => $_POST["editarCuenta"],
                    "banco" => $_POST["editarBanco"]);

                $respuesta = ModeloProveedores::mdlEditarProveedor($tabla, $datos);

                if($respuesta == "ok"){

                    echo'<script>

                    swal({
                          type: "success",
                          title: "El proveedor ha sido cambiado correctamente",
                          showConfirmButton: true,
                          confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
                          }).then(function(result){
                                    if (result.value) {

                                    window.location = "proveedores";

                                    }
                                })

                    </script>';

                }

            }else{

                echo'<script>

                    swal({
                          type: "error",
                          title: "¡El proveedor no puede ir vacío o llevar caracteres especiales!",
                          showConfirmButton: true,
                          confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
                          }).then(function(result){
                            if (result.value) {

                            window.location = "proveedores";

                            }
                        })

                </script>';



            }

        }

    }

}
```

**Modelo**

```php
<?php

class ModeloProveedores{

/* CREAR PROVEEDOR */

static public function mdlIngresarProveedor($tabla, $datos){

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(nombre_empresa, rif, nombre_proveedor, telefono, numero_cuenta, banco) VALUES (:nombre_empresa, :rif, :nombre_proveedor, :telefono, :numero_cuenta, :banco)");

    $stmt->bindParam(":nombre_empresa", $datos["nombre_empresa"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->bindParam(":rif", $datos["rif"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":nombre_proveedor", $datos["nombre_proveedor"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":telefono", $datos["telefono"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":numero_cuenta", $datos["numero_cuenta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":banco", $datos["banco"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($stmt->execute()){

        return "ok";

    }else{

        return "error";

    }

    $stmt->close();
    $stmt = null;

}

/* MOSTRAR PROVEEDOR */

static public function mdlMostrarProveedores($tabla, $item, $valor){

    if($item != null){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");

        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetch();

    }else{

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");

        $stmt -> execute();

        return $stmt -> fetchAll();

    }

    $stmt -> close();

    $stmt = null;

}

/* ACTUALIZAR PROVEEDOR */

/*static public function mdlActualizarProveedor($tabla, $item1, $valor1, $valor){

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET $item1 = :$item1 WHERE id = :id");

    $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item1, $valor1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam("id", $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if($stmt -> execute()){

        return "ok";

    }else{

        return "error";

    }

    $stmt -> close();

    $stmt = null;

    }

}*/

/*=============================================
    EDITAR CLIENTE
    =============================================*/

    static public function mdlEditarProveedor($tabla, $datos){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET nombre_empresa = :nombre_empresa, rif = :rif, nombre_proveedor = :nombre_proveedor, telefono = :telefono, numero_cuenta = :numero_cuenta, banco = :banco WHERE id = :id");

        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $datos["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":nombre_empresa", $datos["nombre_empresa"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":rif", $datos["rif"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":nombre_proveedor", $datos["nombre_proveedor"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":telefono", $datos["telefono"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":numero_cuenta", $datos["numero_cuenta"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":banco", $datos["banco"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()){

            return "ok";

        }else{

            return "error";
        
        }

        $stmt->close();
        $stmt = null;

    }
    }
```

**Vista**

```html
<?php

require_once "controladores/proveedores.controlador.php";
require_once "modelos/proveedores.modelo.php";

if($_SESSION["perfil"] == "Gerente" || $_SESSION["perfil"] == "Vendedor"){ 

  echo '<script>

    window.location = "inicio";

  </script>';

  return;

}

?>

<div class="content-wrapper">

  <section class="content-header">

    <h1>
      Administrar proveedores
    </h1>

    <ol class="breadcrumb">

      <li><a href="inicio"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Inicio</a></li>

      <li class="active">Administrar proveedores</li>

    </ol>
    
  </section>

  <section class="content">

    <div class="box">

      <div class="box-header with-border">

        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAgregarProveedor">

          Agregar proveedor

        </button>

      </div>

      <div class="box-body">

        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped dt-responsive tablas">

          <thead>

            <tr>

              <th style="width:10px">#</th> 
              <th>Nombre de la empresa</th> 
              <th>RIF</th> 
              <th>Nombre del proveedor</th> 
              <th>Teléfono</th> 
              <th>Número de cuenta</th> 
              <th>Banco</th> 
              <th>Acciones</th> 

            </tr> 

          </thead> 

          <tbody>

          <?php

            $item = null;

            $valor = null;

            $proveedor = ControladorProveedores::ctrMostrarProveedores($item, $valor);

            foreach ($proveedor as $key => $value) {

              echo '<tr> 

                      <td>'.($key+1).'</td> 
                      <td>'.$value["nombre_empresa"].'</td> 
                      <td>'.$value["rif"].'</td> 
                      <td>'.$value["nombre_proveedor"].'</td> 
                      <td>'.$value["telefono"].'</td> 
                      <td>'.$value["numero_cuenta"].'</td> 
                      <td>'.$value["banco"].'</td> 
                      <td>

                          <div class="btn-group">
                              <button class="btn btn-warning btnEditarProveedor" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarProveedor" idProveedor="'.$value["id"].'"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                              
                          </div>

                      </td>

                  </tr>';

                  }

          ?>

          </tbody>

        </table>

      </div>

    </div>

  </section>

</div>

<!-- MODAL AGREGAR PROVEEDOR -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modalAgregarProveedor" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <form role="form" method="post">

      <!-- CABEZA DEL MODAL -->
        <div class="modal-header" style="background: #c90003; color: white">

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>

          <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar proveedor</h4>

        </div>

        <!-- CUERPO DEL MODAL -->
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="box-body">

          <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL NOMBRE -->
            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-building"></i></span>

                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoNombreEmpresa" placeholder="Ingresar nombre de la empresa" required>

              </div>

            </div>

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL NUMERO DE RIF-->
            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>

                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoRif" placeholder="Ingresar número de RIF" required>

              </div>

            </div>
            
            <!-- ENTRADA PARA NOMBRE PROVEEDOR -->
            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i></span>

                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoNombreProveedor" placeholder="Ingresar nombre del proveedor"required>

              </div>

            </div>

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL NUMERO DE TELEFONO -->
            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span> 

                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoTelefono" placeholder="Ingresar teléfono" data-inputmask="'mask':'(+99) 999-9999'" data-mask required>

              </div>

            </div>

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA NUMERO DE CUENTA -->
            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></span>

                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevaCuenta" placeholder="Ingresar el número de cuenta" required>

              </div>

            </div>

            <!-- ENTRADA PARA EL BANCO -->
            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-university"></i></span>

                <select class="form-control input-lg" name="nuevoBanco" required>

                    <option value="">Seleccionar banco</option>
                    <option value="100">100% BANCO, BANCO UNIVERSAL, C.A.</option>
                    <option value="BANCAMIGA">BANCAMIGA BANCO UNIVERSAL, C.A.</option>
                    <option value="ACTIVO">BANCO ACTIVO C.A., BANCO UNIVERSAL.</option>
                    <option value="BICENTENARIO">BANCO BICENTENARIO, BANCO UNIVERSAL, C.A.</option>
                    <option value="CARONI">BANCO CARONI, C.A., BANCO UNIVERSAL.</option>
                    <option value="VENEZUELA">BANCO DE VENEZUELA, S.A. BANCO UNIVERSAL.</option>
                    <option value="CARIBE">BANCO DEL CARIBE C.A., BANCO UNIVERSAL (BANCARIBE).</option>
                    <option value="TESORO">BANCO DEL TESORO, C.A., BANCO UNIVERSAL.</option>
                    <option value="EXTERIOR">BANCO EXTERIOR, C.A., BANCO UNIVERSAL.</option>
                    <option value="BNC">BANCO NACIONAL DE CREDITO, C.A. BANCO UNIVERSAL.</option>
                    <option value="PLAZA">BANCO PLAZA, C.A., BANCO UNIVERSAL.</option>
                    <option value="PROVINCIAL">BANCO PROVINCIAL, S.A. BANCO UNIVERSAL.</option>
                    <option value="SOFITASA">BANCO SOFITASA BANCO UNIVERSAL, C.A.</option>
                    <option value="BANCRECER">BANCRECER, S.A. BANCO MICROFINANCIERO.</option>
                    <option value="BANESCO">BANESCO BANCO UNIVERSAL, C.A.</option>
                    <option value="BANPLUS">BANPLUS BANCO UNIVERSAL, C.A.</option>
                    <option value="BFC">BFC BANCO FONDO COMUN, C.A. BANCO UNIVERSAL.</option>
                    <option value="DELSUR">DEL SUR BANCO UNIVERSAL, C.A.</option>
                    <option value="MERCANTIL">MERCANTIL, C.A., BANCO UNIVERSAL.</option>
                    <option value="MIBANCO">MI BANCO, BANCO MICROFINANCIERO, C.A.</option>
                    <option value="ITALO">VENEZOLANO DE CREDITO, S.A., BANCO UNIVERSAL.</option>
                    <option value="N58">N58 BANCO DIGITAL, BANCO MICROFINANCIERO, S.A.</option>

                </select>

              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

        <!-- FOOTER DEL MODAL -->
        <div class="modal-footer">

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" color="white" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Guardar Proveedor</button>

        </div>

        <?php

          $crearProveedor = new ControladorProveedores();
          $crearProveedor -> ctrCrearProveedor();

        ?>

      </form>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<!-- MODAL EDITAR PROVEEDOR -->
<div id="modalEditarProveedor" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <form role="form" method="post">

        <div class="modal-header" style="background:#c90003; color:white">

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

          <h4 class="modal-title">Editar proveedor</h4>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="box-body">

            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-building"></i></span> 

                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="editarNombreEmpresa" id="editarNombreEmpresa" required>

                <input type="hidden" id="idNombreEmpresa" name="idNombreEmpresa">

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span> 

                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="editarRif" id="editarRif" required>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i></span> 

                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="editarNombreProveedor" id="editarNombreProveedor" required>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>

                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="editarTelefono" id="editarTelefono" data-inputmask="'mask':'(999) 999-9999'" data-mask required>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">
                
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></span>

                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="editarCuenta" id="editarCuenta"  required>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

              <div class="input-group">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-university"></i></span> 

                <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="editarBanco" id="editarBanco" required>

              </div>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Guardar cambios</button>

        </div>

        <?php

          $editarProveedor = new ControladorProveedores();
          $editarProveedor -> ctrEditarProveedor();

        ?>
      </form>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```js
/*=============================================
EDITAR PROVEEDOR
=============================================*/
$(".tablas").on("click", ".btnEditarProveedor", function(){

    var idProveedor = $(this).attr("idProveedor");

    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("idProveedor", idProveedor);

    $.ajax({

      url:"ajax/proveedores.ajax.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: datos,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      dataType:"json",
      success:function(respuesta){
      
           $("#idProveedor").val(respuesta["id"]);
           $("#editarProveedor").val(respuesta["nombre_empresa"]);
           $("#editarRIF").val(respuesta["rif"]);
           $("#editarNombre").val(respuesta["nombre_proveedor"]);
           $("#editarTelefono").val(respuesta["telefono"]);
           $("#editarCuenta").val(respuesta["numero_cuenta"]);
           $("#editarBanco").val(respuesta["banco"]);
      }

    })

})

/*=============================================
ELIMINAR PROVEEDOR
=============================================*/
$(".tablas").on("click", ".btnEliminarProveedor", function(){

    var idProveedor = $(this).attr("idProveedor");
    
    swal({
        title: '¿Está seguro de borrar el proveedor?',
        text: "¡Si no lo está puede cancelar la acción!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
        confirmButtonText: 'Si, borrar proveedor!'
      }).then(function(result){
        if (result.value) {
          
            window.location = "index.php?ruta=proveedores&idProveedor="+idProveedor;
        }

  })

})
```

**Capturas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Buen dia, necesito guardar los proveedores ingresados al formulario, pero no se guardan los datos en la BD, ese es el problema especifico, he revisado e intentado pero no he logrado resolver

Comment: Hay mil lineas de codigo aca, pero nada claro como para resolver tu problema.. empecemos por el principio.. La llamada a tu controlador se hace?

Comment: Ok entiendo... Si la llamada al controlador se hace, igual al modelo se hace, pero no guarda los datos en la BD, pero si ingreso esos datos directamente en la BD si se reflejan en la pagina

Comment: El guardado no tira un error? el controlador llega a la parte de guardar? estas mirando siempre la misma db? Donde esta la parte que guarda de tu codigo (que es donde falla y lo que deberiamos estar mirando?)

Comment: ¿Por qué tu `form` no utiliza un _action_? De igual manera: describe tu código, tal como te indicaron. Lee [ask]. En lugar de revisar línea por línea, describe brevemente el comportamiento de tu código, como para tener una rápida noción de lo que hace.

Comment: @gbianchi, no tira ningun error, la pagina se actualiza y no muestra el alerta suave q corresponde, bien sea success o error, por eso solo publique capture del formulario, es como si funcionara pero en realidad no guarda los datos en la bd, gracias!

Comment: @padaleiana, voy a utilizar el action y te doy respuesta, gracias!